Frage zu einem Satz: wenn, als und die Gleichzeitigkeit
Diese Frage bezieht sich auf den Ausdruck der Gleichzeitigkeit und auch auf eine frühere Frage von mir, die von der Verwendung von als und wenn bei der Gleichzeitigkeit handelte.
Wenn man so einen Satz hat

Man hört das Nuscheln des Mannes, als er durch die Straßen spaziert.

Ist es besser (oder notwendig) zu sagen

Man hört das Nuscheln des Mannes, wenn er durch die Straßen spaziert.

Ich hätte gedacht, dass der erste Satz korrekt wäre, um die Gleichzeitigkeit der Aktionen auszudrücken, aber man hat mir gesagt, dass der zweite der richtige ist.  Meines Erachtens drücken sie zwei verschiedene Sachen aus: der erste Satz drückt Gleichzeitigkeit aus, während der zweite von einem Ereignis spricht, das mehrmals geschehen könnte.  Im Englischen wären sie dann:

One hears the mumbling of the man, as he walks through the streets.


One hears the mumbling of the man, when/whenever he walks through the streets.


Du analysierst das vollkommen richtig.

Beide Sätze sind korrekt, aber sie sagen etwas unterschiedliches aus.

Man hört das Nuscheln des Mannes, als er durch die Straßen spaziert.

Hier wird das Spazieren des Mannes als eine Tatsache geschildert, die gerade stattfindet oder die bereits stattgefunden hat. Im letzteren Fall ist Präsens hier eher ungewöhnlich, weil Vorgänge, die bereits stattgefunden haben, üblicherweise in der Vergangenheit geschildert werden. Es kommt allerdings auch vor, dass das Präsens als Erzähltempus für Tatsachen gewählt wird, die bereits geschehen sind.

Man hört das Nuscheln des Mannes, wenn er durch die Straßen spaziert.

Hier wird der Vorgang nicht als etwas geschildert, das zu einem konkreten Zeitpunkt stattfindet oder stattgefunden hat, sondern als etwas Hypothetisches oder auch als etwas, das wiederholt stattfindet.

Noch besser passt "während", um die Gleichzeitigkeit auszudrücken:

Man hört das Nuscheln des Mannes, während er durch die Straßen spaziert.


Während hier unterscheidet nicht zwischen der Gleichzeitig zweier konkreter Ereignisse („als“) und der generellen Gleichzeitigkeit („wann immer“).
